# How to Make a function calculator in Xcode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode

So I need to make a simple app in Xcode 4.2, I already have the layout set, there is just one thing I'm stuck on. I need to make a calculator in which someone could input several numbers which would go into an equation then when you click submit the result pops up on the page.

For example

Estimated Hourly rate:

Estimated material cost:

Estimated Hours:

then you would click submit and on the next page you would see

Approximate cost:

Now the thing I need to know is how to use that formula in Xcode and get the next screen to display that cost. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Lets start with "what have you tried?" Then work from there.

Comment: Do you want to calculate an expression? If so, you'll need to write a parser.

Answer (score 0):

Start with Empty View template, in IB add labels and UITextField for each of input value, then add UIButton. Connect everything to your variables in *.h, synthesize them in *.m file. Create IBAction for UIButton, where you read values user entered in UITextFields, perform your formula then display it to user.

I would suggest to You reading some basic tutorials, it's pretty simple App.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a tutorial about how to make a calculator on iPhone, check 
 **iPad and iPhone Application Development** iTunes U free courses here: http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/ipad-iphone-application-development/id473757255

It is on iTunes U by Paul Hegarty from Standford University. This is a great tutorial used by lots of developers, and I highly recommand this course. The very first or two classes was how to implement a calculator. That is a simple mathmatical calculator which is probably different from what you need, but you can get some useful ideas from it.

Hope this helps.